# Getting Column Invalid in select list because not contained in an aggregate function or Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run the following code via DataDirect ODBC Driver, it is throwing  the

> "Column 'dbo.LD.LaborCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or a Group By clause."

This has been working fine for quite a while and has now only started throwing this error.

```
SELECT        LaborCode, SUM(RegHrs + OvtHrs) AS Hours
FROM            dbo.LD
WHERE        (WBS1 IN ('0851.190791.20')) AND (TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/1901' AND '3/27/2019')
GROUP BY LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to repeat the same expression in `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1) AS LaborCode, 
       SUM(RegHrs + OvtHrs) AS [Hours]
FROM dbo.LD
WHERE WBS1 IN ('0851.190791.20') AND TransDate BETWEEN '1901-01-01' AND '2019-03-27'
GROUP BY LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1);
```

However, i would use `APPLY` instead :

```
SELECT L.LaborCode, SUM(RegHrs + OvtHrs) AS [Hours]
FROM dbo.LD CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1)) 
     ) L(LaborCode)
WHERE WBS1 IN ('0851.190791.20') AND TransDate BETWEEN '1901-01-01' AND '2019-03-27'
GROUP BY L.LaborCode;
```

Comment: yep, thank you.  I am guessing this part of my code has never ran until now and in reality never did work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        LaborCode, SUM(RegHrs + OvtHrs) AS Hours
FROM            dbo.LD
WHERE        (WBS1 IN ('0851.190791.20')) AND (TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/1901' AND 
'3/27/2019')
GROUP BY LaborCode
```

or this

```
SELECT   LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1)     LaborCode, SUM(RegHrs + OvtHrs) AS Hours
FROM            dbo.LD
WHERE        (WBS1 IN ('0851.190791.20')) AND (TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/1901' 
AND '3/27/2019')
GROUP BY LEFT(LaborCode, LEN(LaborCode) - 1)
```